# CORS Issue with Angular and Lambda

Tags: angular, cors

I am calling a simple API from Angular but it keeps giving me CORS issues, I am in control of the API, which is built using serverless on Lambda.

I am setting the headers in the API to allow all:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {return {
statusCode: 200,
headers: {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
},
body: JSON.stringify(
  {
    message: "This is protected!",
    input: event,
  },
  null,
  2
),};};
```

Excuse the formatting above, SO is not letting me format code correctly.

I am calling the API as follows:

```
  async postTest() {
const path = BASE_URL + '/test';
console.log('Posting');
return await this.http.post<any>(path, {
  'test': 'This is a test'
},
{
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'secretToken'
  }
}
).subscribe(data => {
  console.log('????:', data);
});
```

}

All I am getting is the following error:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://5irodm1edc.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

When I test with Postman I see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin coming through, when I run it using Angular it gives the above error.

Comment: It is worth noting that I have also specifically specified http://localhost:4200 in the origin header with the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

preflight request is another automatic request sent by browser with method=OPTIONS. most likely you aren't handling it.

you shouldn't handle cors by yourself (you can, but why). Better use aws capabilities to handle this problem
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Cors.html

Comment: I did look into this, but I am using the Serverless framework, their documentation isn't great on this side of things too.  I tried cors: true/false and also cors: origin: '*' as per this document, with the same outcome: https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, two things are needed:

1. From your Lambda, return the response with the header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"`. This you already have.
2. In your *index.ts* file of the Lambda (assuming you are using serverless with TS), add `cors: true` to the `http` object as follows

```js
export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  events: [
    {
      http: {
        method: "post",
        path: "test",
        cors: true, // add this
      },
    },
  ],
  // ... other items
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using JS at this point, but as I am so early in this project, I am happy to switch over to TS, I prefer it typed anyway.  I did add cors: true to the serverless.yms under the events/httpApi, but this gave me warnings: Warning: Invalid configuration encountered -> unrecognized property 'cors'.  I will rebuild using TypeScript and your above advice and see how that pans out.

Comment: In my case, index.ts is at function level. Its not serverless.ts (serverless.yml in your case). I am also new to AWS and don't understand everything is very detail